# nginx not working: subdomain and domain pointing to one server

Tags: nginx

I am trying to access domain and subdomain using following

```
upstream webapp {
    server webapp:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app.unicornpost.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # https://serverfault.com/a/993559
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800;
        send_timeout 1800;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;

    server_name unicornpost.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

but i see both subdomain and domain point to one

Comment: Yu should specify `root` in your first server config. It default to `html`, which might be the same location as your second server? (see: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root )